# Recursive Matching using CTE Query in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, pattern-matching, common-table-expression

I have two tables (they are defined below and you can use the SQL below to build them)

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'ETab')
DROP TABLE ETab;
GO

CREATE TABLE ETab 
    ([MRN] varchar(20), [LSPEC] varchar(2), [ADT] DATETIME, [SDT] DATETIME, [Source] varchar(20), [Enum] varchar(20));
GO

INSERT INTO ETab ([MRN], [LSPEC], [ADT], [SDT], [Source], [Enum]) 
VALUES 
    ('HOMECARE',    'HM',       CONVERT(datetime, '2017-04-01 00:00:00.000', 20),   CONVERT(datetime, '2017-04-30 00:00:00.000', 20),   'PRODPAT',  'HOMEBLD04'),
    ('HOMECARE',    'HM',       CONVERT(datetime, '2017-05-01 00:00:00.000', 20),   CONVERT(datetime, '2017-05-31 00:00:00.000', 20),   'PRODPAT',  'HOMEBLD05'),
    ('HOMECARE',    'HM',       CONVERT(datetime, '2017-06-01 00:00:00.000', 20),   CONVERT(datetime, '2017-06-30 00:00:00.000', 20),   'PRODPAT',  'HOMEBLD06'),
    ('HOMECARE',    'HM',       CONVERT(datetime, '2017-07-01 00:00:00.000', 20),   CONVERT(datetime, '2017-07-31 00:00:00.000', 20),   'PRODPAT',  'HOMEBLD07'),
    ('HOMECARE',    'HM',       CONVERT(datetime, '2017-08-01 00:00:00.000', 20),   CONVERT(datetime, '2017-08-31 00:00:00.000', 20),   'PRODPAT',  'HOMEBLD08'),
    ('HOMECARE',    'HM',       CONVERT(datetime, '2017-09-01 00:00:00.000', 20),   CONVERT(datetime, '2017-09-30 00:00:00.000', 20),   'PRODPAT',  'HOMEBLD09'),
    ('HOMECARE',    'HQ',       CONVERT(datetime, '2017-04-01 00:00:00.000', 20),   CONVERT(datetime, '2017-04-30 00:00:00.000', 20),   'PRODPAT',  'HOMEDRG04HM'),
    ('HOMECARE',    'HM',       CONVERT(datetime, '2017-05-01 00:00:00.000', 20),   CONVERT(datetime, '2017-05-31 00:00:00.000', 20),   'PRODPAT',  'HOMEDRG05HM'),
    ('HOMECARE',    'HM',       CONVERT(datetime, '2017-06-01 00:00:00.000', 20),   CONVERT(datetime, '2017-06-30 00:00:00.000', 20),   'PRODPAT',  'HOMEDRG06HM'),
    ('HOMECARE',    'HM',       CONVERT(datetime, '2017-07-01 00:00:00.000', 20),   CONVERT(datetime, '2017-07-31 00:00:00.000', 20),   'PRODPAT',  'HOMEDRG07HM'),
    ('HOMECARE',    'HM',       CONVERT(datetime, '2017-08-01 00:00:00.000', 20),   CONVERT(datetime, '2017-08-31 00:00:00.000', 20),   'PRODPAT',  'HOMEDRG08HM'),
    ('HOMECARE',    'HM',       CONVERT(datetime, '2017-09-01 00:00:00.000', 20),   CONVERT(datetime, '2017-09-30 00:00:00.000', 20),   'PRODPAT',  'HOMEDRG09HM'), 
    ('111824',      'UR',       CONVERT(datetime, '2017-09-22 00:00:00.000', 20),   CONVERT(datetime, '2017-09-22 00:00:00.000', 20),   'OP',   'OP1118240003'),
    ('111824',      'NL',       CONVERT(datetime, '2017-04-19 00:00:00.000', 20),   CONVERT(datetime, '2017-04-19 00:00:00.000', 20),   'OP',   'OP1118240001'),
    ('111824',      'MS',       CONVERT(datetime, '2017-06-30 00:00:00.000', 20),   CONVERT(datetime, '2017-06-30 00:00:00.000', 20),   'OP',   'OP1118240002'),
    ('111824',      'MS',       CONVERT(datetime, '2017-04-24 00:00:00.000', 20),   CONVERT(datetime, '2017-04-24 00:00:00.000', 20),   'IP',   'IP1118240001'),
    ('111824',      'MS',       CONVERT(datetime, '2017-04-28 00:00:00.000', 20),   CONVERT(datetime, '2017-04-28 00:00:00.000', 20),   'IP',   'IP1118240005'),
    ('111824',      'MS',       CONVERT(datetime, '2017-04-27 00:00:00.000', 20),   CONVERT(datetime, '2017-04-27 00:00:00.000', 20),   'IP',   'IP1118240004'),
    ('111824',      'MS',       CONVERT(datetime, '2017-04-26 00:00:00.000', 20),   CONVERT(datetime, '2017-04-26 00:00:00.000', 20),   'IP',   'IP1118240003'),
    ('111824',      'MS',       CONVERT(datetime, '2017-04-25 00:00:00.000', 20),   CONVERT(datetime, '2017-04-25 00:00:00.000', 20),   'IP',   'IP1118240002');
GO

IF EXISTS (SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'UTab')
DROP TABLE UTab;
GO

CREATE TABLE UTab 
    (MRN varchar(20), SIDate DATETIME, LSPEC varchar(2), Source varchar(20), Enum varchar(20), Iteration varchar(20));
GO

INSERT INTO UTab 
    (MRN, SIDate, LSPEC, Source, Enum, Iteration) 
VALUES 
('HOMECARE', CONVERT(datetime, '2017-04-20 00:00:00.000', 20), 'HM', 'N', NULL, NULL), 
('HOMECARE', CONVERT(datetime, '2017-04-20 00:00:00.000', 20), 'HM', 'N', NULL, NULL), 
('HOMECARE', CONVERT(datetime, '2017-04-20 00:00:00.000', 20), 'HM', 'N', NULL, NULL), 
('HOMECARE', CONVERT(datetime, '2017-04-20 00:00:00.000', 20), 'HM', 'N', NULL, NULL), 
('HOMECARE', CONVERT(datetime, '2017-04-20 00:00:00.000', 20), 'HM', 'N', NULL, NULL), 
('HOMECARE', CONVERT(datetime, '2017-04-20 00:00:00.000', 20), 'HM', 'N', NULL, NULL), 
('HOMECARE', CONVERT(datetime, '2017-04-30 00:00:00.000', 20), 'HM', 'N', NULL, NULL), 
('HOMECARE', CONVERT(datetime, '2017-04-30 00:00:00.000', 20), 'HM', 'N', NULL, NULL), 
('HOMECARE', CONVERT(datetime, '2017-04-30 00:00:00.000', 20), 'HM', 'N', NULL, NULL), 
('HOMECARE', CONVERT(datetime, '2017-04-20 00:00:00.000', 20), 'HM', 'N', NULL, NULL), 
('HOMECARE', CONVERT(datetime, '2017-04-30 00:00:00.000', 20), 'HM', 'N', NULL, NULL), 
('HOMECARE', CONVERT(datetime, '2017-04-30 00:00:00.000', 20), 'HM', 'N', NULL, NULL), 
('HOMECARE', CONVERT(datetime, '2017-05-17 00:00:00.000', 20), 'HM', 'N', NULL, NULL), 
('HOMECARE', CONVERT(datetime, '2017-04-30 00:00:00.000', 20), 'HQ', 'N', NULL, NULL), 
('HOMECARE', CONVERT(datetime, '2017-04-30 00:00:00.000', 20), 'HM', 'N', NULL, NULL), 
('HOMECARE', CONVERT(datetime, '2017-04-30 00:00:00.000', 20), 'HM', 'N', NULL, NULL), 
('HOMECARE', CONVERT(datetime, '2017-05-30 00:00:00.000', 20), 'HM', 'N', NULL, NULL), 
('HOMECARE', CONVERT(datetime, '2017-06-01 00:00:00.000', 20), 'HM', 'N', NULL, NULL), 
('HOMECARE', CONVERT(datetime, '2017-06-01 00:00:00.000', 20), 'HM', 'N', NULL, NULL), 
('HOMECARE', CONVERT(datetime, '2017-06-01 00:00:00.000', 20), 'HM', 'N', NULL, NULL), 
('HOMECARE', CONVERT(datetime, '2017-06-01 00:00:00.000', 20), 'HM', 'N', NULL, NULL), 
('HOMECARE', CONVERT(datetime, '2017-06-01 00:00:00.000', 20), 'HM', 'N', NULL, NULL), 
('HOMECARE', CONVERT(datetime, '2017-06-01 00:00:00.000', 20), 'HM', 'N', NULL, NULL), 
('HOMECARE', CONVERT(datetime, '2017-05-30 00:00:00.000', 20), 'HM', 'N', NULL, NULL), 
('HOMECARE', CONVERT(datetime, '2017-06-01 00:00:00.000', 20), 'HM', 'N', NULL, NULL), 
('HOMECARE', CONVERT(datetime, '2017-06-26 00:00:00.000', 20), 'HM', 'N', NULL, NULL), 
('HOMECARE', CONVERT(datetime, '2017-06-26 00:00:00.000', 20), 'HM', 'N', NULL, NULL), 
('HOMECARE', CONVERT(datetime, '2017-06-26 00:00:00.000', 20), 'HM', 'N', NULL, NULL), 
('HOMECARE', CONVERT(datetime, '2017-06-26 00:00:00.000', 20), 'HM', 'N', NULL, NULL), 
('HOMECARE', CONVERT(datetime, '2017-06-26 00:00:00.000', 20), 'HM', 'N', NULL, NULL), 
('HOMECARE', CONVERT(datetime, '2017-06-26 00:00:00.000', 20), 'HM', 'N', NULL, NULL), 
('HOMECARE', CONVERT(datetime, '2017-06-26 00:00:00.000', 20), 'HM', 'N', NULL, NULL), 
('HOMECARE', CONVERT(datetime, '2017-06-26 00:00:00.000', 20), 'HM', 'N', NULL, NULL), 
('HOMECARE', CONVERT(datetime, '2017-06-26 00:00:00.000', 20), 'HM', 'N', NULL, NULL), 
('HOMECARE', CONVERT(datetime, '2017-06-26 00:00:00.000', 20), 'HM', 'N', NULL, NULL), 
('HOMECARE', CONVERT(datetime, '2017-06-26 00:00:00.000', 20), 'HM', 'N', NULL, NULL), 
('HOMECARE', CONVERT(datetime, '2017-06-26 00:00:00.000', 20), 'HM', 'N', NULL, NULL), 
('HOMECARE', CONVERT(datetime, '2017-06-26 00:00:00.000', 20), 'HM', 'N', NULL, NULL), 
('HOMECARE', CONVERT(datetime, '2017-06-26 00:00:00.000', 20), 'HM', 'N', NULL, NULL), 
('HOMECARE', CONVERT(datetime, '2017-06-26 00:00:00.000', 20), 'HM', 'N', NULL, NULL), 
('HOMECARE', CONVERT(datetime, '2017-06-26 00:00:00.000', 20), 'HM', 'N', NULL, NULL), 
('HOMECARE', CONVERT(datetime, '2017-06-26 00:00:00.000', 20), 'HM', 'N', NULL, NULL), 
('HOMECARE', CONVERT(datetime, '2017-06-26 00:00:00.000', 20), 'HM', 'N', NULL, NULL), 
('HOMECARE', CONVERT(datetime, '2017-05-30 00:00:00.000', 20), 'HM', 'N', NULL, NULL), 
('HOMECARE', CONVERT(datetime, '2017-05-30 00:00:00.000', 20), 'HM', 'N', NULL, NULL), 
('HOMECARE', CONVERT(datetime, '2017-05-04 00:00:00.000', 20), 'HM', 'N', NULL, NULL), 
('HOMECARE', CONVERT(datetime, '2017-05-04 00:00:00.000', 20), 'HM', 'N', NULL, NULL), 
('HOMECARE', CONVERT(datetime, '2017-05-04 00:00:00.000', 20), 'HM', 'N', NULL, NULL), 
('HOMECARE', CONVERT(datetime, '2017-05-04 00:00:00.000', 20), 'HM', 'N', NULL, NULL), 
('HOMECARE', CONVERT(datetime, '2017-05-04 00:00:00.000', 20), 'HM', 'N', NULL, NULL), 
('HOMECARE', CONVERT(datetime, '2017-05-04 00:00:00.000', 20), 'HM', 'N', NULL, NULL), 
('HOMECARE', CONVERT(datetime, '2017-05-04 00:00:00.000', 20), 'HM', 'N', NULL, NULL), 
('HOMECARE', CONVERT(datetime, '2017-05-04 00:00:00.000', 20), 'HM', 'N', NULL, NULL), 
('HOMECARE', CONVERT(datetime, '2017-05-04 00:00:00.000', 20), 'HM', 'N', NULL, NULL), 
('HOMECARE', CONVERT(datetime, '2017-05-04 00:00:00.000', 20), 'HM', 'N', NULL, NULL), 
('HOMECARE', CONVERT(datetime, '2017-05-04 00:00:00.000', 20), 'HM', 'N', NULL, NULL), 
('HOMECARE', CONVERT(datetime, '2017-05-04 00:00:00.000', 20), 'HM', 'N', NULL, NULL), 
('HOMECARE', CONVERT(datetime, '2017-05-04 00:00:00.000', 20), 'HM', 'N', NULL, NULL), 
('HOMECARE', CONVERT(datetime, '2017-05-04 00:00:00.000', 20), 'HM', 'N', NULL, NULL), 
('HOMECARE', CONVERT(datetime, '2017-05-04 00:00:00.000', 20), 'HM', 'N', NULL, NULL), 
('HOMECARE', CONVERT(datetime, '2017-05-04 00:00:00.000', 20), 'HM', 'N', NULL, NULL),
('111824', CONVERT(datetime, '2017-04-21 00:00:00.000', 20), 'MS', 'IP', NULL, NULL), 
('111824', CONVERT(datetime, '2017-04-24 00:00:00.000', 20), 'NL', 'OP', NULL, NULL), 
('111824', CONVERT(datetime, '2017-04-27 00:00:00.000', 20), 'NL', 'OP', NULL, NULL), 
('111824', CONVERT(datetime, '2017-04-20 00:00:00.000', 20), 'NL', 'OP', NULL, NULL), 
('111824', CONVERT(datetime, '2017-04-20 00:00:00.000', 20), 'NL', 'OP', NULL, NULL), 
('111824', CONVERT(datetime, '2017-04-20 00:00:00.000', 20), 'NL', 'OP', NULL, NULL);
GO

SELECT * FROM ETab
WHERE Source = 'PRODPAT' AND LSPEC = 'HM' 
GO

SELECT * FROM UTab  
WHERE LSPEC = 'HM';
GO

IF EXISTS (SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = '__Tmp')
DROP TABLE __Tmp;
GO
```

I have a C# application in which the user requests certian matching clauses at run-time. Using the information specified by the user, I generate some SQL that is executed and updates `UTab`.

Via the generated SQL, I wish to perform some matching which updates the `[UTab].[Enum]` based on the link field `[MRN]` and whether `[UTab].[SIDate]` lies within `[ETab].[ADT]` and `[ETab].[SDT]` +- some days before or after which are specified by the user. So, the user might specify two commands, the first:

```
MatchCmd:MRN,LSPEC:ETab:UTab:ADT:SDT:SIDate:0:1:'Iteration#1':WHERE [UTab].[Source] = 'OP' AND [UTab].[LSPEC] = [ETab].[LSPEC]
```

> This says, match on `MRN` AND `LSPEC` from source table `ETab`, updating `UTab` where `SIDate > ADT - 0 day(s)` and `SIDate < SDT + 1 day(s)` and where `[UTab].[Source] = 'OP'` - any matches I mark with the "iteration number" `Iteration#1`.

My code generates the following SQL:

```
;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT [ETab].[Enum] AS Enum, 
           [ETab].[MRN] AS Link, 
           [ETab].[ADT] AS ADT, 
           [ETab].[SDT] AS SDT, 
           [UTab].[SIDate] AS DT, 
           [ETab].[MRN] AS [MRN], 
           [ETab].[LSPEC] AS [LSPEC], 
           [ETab].[Source] AS [Source], 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [UTab].[MRN], [UTab].[LSPEC], [UTab].[SIDate] 
                ORDER BY ABS(DATEDIFF(mi, [UTab].[SIDate], [ETab].[ADT]))) AS Idx, 
           ABS(DATEDIFF(mi, [UTab].[SIDate], [ETab].[ADT])) AS Diff 
    FROM [UTab] 
        LEFT JOIN [ETab] ON [UTab].[MRN] = [ETab].[MRN] 
    WHERE ([UTab].[SIDate] BETWEEN 
        DATEADD(dd, -0, [ETab].[ADT]) AND 
        DATEADD(dd, 1, [ETab].[SDT]) AND [Iteration] IS NULL) 
            AND ETab.Source = 'OP' 
)  SELECT * 
   INTO __Tmp 
   FROM cte; 
GO
```

To get all the records that match the criteria (laying within the time window and abiding by custom where clauses). Then I Update the `[UTab].[Enum]` and `[UTab].[Iteration]` via another generated query

```
UPDATE [UTab] 
SET [ENum] = [__Tmp].[ENum], [Iteration] = N'Iteration#1' 
--SELECT __Tmp.ENum, __Tmp.Link, __Tmp.LSPEC, __Tmp.ADT, __Tmp.SDT, __Tmp.DT, __Tmp.Idx 
FROM [UTab] AS up 
    INNER JOIN [__Tmp] 
        ON [up].[MRN] = [__Tmp].[Link] 
           AND [up].[SIDate] = [__Tmp].[DT] 
           AND [up].[LSPEC] = [__Tmp].[LSPEC] 
WHERE __Tmp.Idx = 1;
```

This seems to work okay, but some questions:

Q. Is there anything clearly ary with the method/SQL I am using?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: If you broke this down to a simpler problem I think you could get better answers.   The written requirements are not clear to me.

Comment: In Your first query you need to move everything from the `where` clause to the `on` clause. In the update statement it's best to move `AND up.SIDate = __Tmp.DT` and `AND up.LSPEC = __Tmp.LSPEC` to the `on` clause for semantics, but it's not critical.

Comment: If Q2 is now redundant since you edited this question, is it worth another edit to remove the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The CTE usage was a bit strange to me, since you're not really doing much with it in the subsequent query. I'd move that to the UPDATE.

The query doesn't really join on the **Source**. I'm not sure if it's meant to do that or not. If UTab has multiple sources for MRN/LSPEC combination, that might result in an issue.

So, I come up with something like:

```
DECLARE @ADT_Adjustment INT = 0;
DECLARE @SDT_Adjustment INT = 1;
DECLARE @Iteration INT = 1;

WITH SequencedJoin AS (
    SELECT
        ETab.MRN, ETab.LSPEC, ETab.ADT, ETab.SDT, UTab.SIDate, ETab.Enum, ETab.[Source], UTab.Enum AS WriteEnum, UTab.Iteration AS WriteIteration
    ,   DENSE_RANK() OVER ( 
            PARTITION BY UTab.MRN, UTab.LSPEC, UTab.[Source], UTab.SIDate 
            ORDER BY ABS( DATEDIFF( MINUTE, UTab.SIDate, ETab.ADT ) ) 
        ) AS Ordinal
    FROM
        @UTab AS UTab
    JOIN    @ETab AS ETab ON (
            ETab.MRN = UTab.MRN
        AND ETab.LSPEC = UTab.LSPEC
        AND ETab.[Source] = UTab.[Source]
        AND UTab.SIDate BETWEEN DATEADD( dd, -@ADT_Adjustment, ETab.ADT ) AND DATEADD( dd, @SDT_Adjustment, ETab.SDT )
        )
    WHERE
        UTab.Iteration IS NULL
)
UPDATE
    SequencedJoin
SET
    WriteEnum = SequencedJoin.Enum
,   WriteIteration = N'Iteration#' + CAST( @Iteration AS VARCHAR( 2 ) )
WHERE
    SequencedJoin.[Source] = 'OP'
AND SequencedJoin.Ordinal = 1
```

Answer (score 3):

`up.L != cte.L` since you are looking for anything conforming your conditions and filtering by `rn`.

```
SELECT cte.E, [Iteration] = N'00-00-00-CA', *
FROM [Up] 
    INNER JOIN cte ON [Up].[M] = [cte].[M] AND [cte].[rn] = 1
WHERE [cte].[E] IS NOT NULL AND (
    [Up].[DTE] BETWEEN 
        DATEADD(dd, -0, [cte].[ADT]) AND 
        DATEADD(dd, 0, [cte].[SDT])) 
            AND [Up].[F] = 'Y' 
            AND [Up].[S] = 'HC' 
            ----comment this line
            --AND [Up].[L] = [cte].[L]; -- <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/d1483/2/0

I modified some data: added `ZZ` which broke your query totally. Only two rows became matching.

ps 
fixed insert issue with length of `E` column and col name listed in first insert.

Comment: But removing `AND [Up].[L] = [cte].[L]` then breaks the first query.

Comment: Inside cte I guess you do need it. But in the outer query it does not make sense to me.

Answer (score 2):

Not a complete answer as such, but this index will speed up you CTE:

```
CREATE INDEX T1 ON UTAB (
    MRN,
    SIDATE
)
INCLUDE
(
    LSPEC,
    Iteration
)
```